# What commands must I learn to become an effective Linux shell script programmer?

Tags: linux, command-line, shell

I have recently started moving into the world of Linux development. I wanted to learn some new things and thought bash might be fun. As I learn more about bash programming I have found that there are quite an assortment of useful tools to be used (such as `grep`, `tr`, `awk`, etc.) There are so many that I just do not know which ones are "vital" to learn.

Shell scripting commands depend heavily on the configuration of the system itself, and can change drastically over time, unlike most programming languages (where a core library ships with the language itself and represents the "core" set of commands that a programmer would use when interacting with the outside world). Therefore,

As a modern Linux shell script programmer, which command line tools should I be familiar with?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576/what-should-a-longtime-windows-user-know-when-starting-to-use-linux

Comment: Edited, in an attempt to differentiate this from the previous question (should be a sufficient difference between "programmer using the OS" and "programmer scripting the shell")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Compressing and uncompressing various archives.
- Using the *man* pages
- *alias* is always helpful
- as mentioned by others *sed* & *grep* (RegEx is good to know in general), *sort*, *head*, *tr*, *cut*
- *echo* & *printf* (their differences and when to use what)
- Getting the return value (not as useful but still handy when writing scripts) via *$?*
- *top*, *ps*, *kill*, how to background/foreground/suspend a process

The important thing is combining the many tools that exists and where most become extremely useful.  Using *man* whenever you are stuck is probably the most important thing.

Comment: good point, I forgot about man, it is so easy to forget the basics.

Comment: I don't think it is that we forget the basics, it's sometimes so obvious we don't mention it.  Sometimes you just do it without thought and assume everyone would as well.

Comment: In 1995, it would (perhaps) have been appropriate to include `alias` on a list of things to know for interactive use of a shell.  It was never appropriate for scripting, and in the modern world is not even appropriate for interactive use.

Comment: I agree that 'alias' is probably not great for scripting (portability and whatnot) but if portability is not a major concern it's still something that happens fairly common. Sometimes aliases are exported and `source`ed for scripts too.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at [commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/browse). People come up with all sorts of things there, and you're bound to find examples of stuff which may be useful in the future.

But generally, top used commands, by [John](http://blog.sontek.net/2008/03/20/my-top-15-commands/) are nice as a guidance.

And of course, **here be dragons**, list of stuff **you shouldn't do:** [deadly ones](http://www.junauza.com/2008/11/7-deadly-linux-commands.html)

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend especially that you become familiar with locate, grep and find. sed, awk and vim are next, and around these are cat, less, tail / head, ls (yes, ls!), and the many ways in which bash can help you.

Especially about Bash: beware of bashisms!

Answer (score 2):

You should know *some* console-based text editor. Pico might suffice. I myself am a [vi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) guy, though [Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) is also acceptable. (Though I will recommend vi: that is a de-facto standard on nearly any platform of Unix, and things like [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep)/[sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) behave very similar to vi.)

Others:

[Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen): *extremely* useful when you don't have a GUI or don't want to/can't open up many terminal windows or [PuTTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) sessions. Allows you to have multiple shell sessions open, and you can toggle between them (and many other things.

[top](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_(software)): good for monitoring processes, CPU usage, and memory usage

[watch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watch_(command)): runs a command every "n" seconds and displays its output. E.g., `watch -n 1 "ls -aio"` executes "ls -aio" every time 1 second.

Comment: +1 for mentioning screen. For remote sessions, screen is invaluable.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you're doing, obviously, but I get a lot of mileage out of `find`, `grep`, `rsync`, and `ssh`.  The simple ones are useful, too:  `cat`, `tail`, `wc`, `ps`.  There's a lot you can do with a `for` loop, too, and wildcard syntax is essential.  For example,

```
  $ for i in {app,web}{01,02}; do ssh $i date; done
```

That will ssh into hosts app01, app02, web01, and web02 and execute the `date` command on each one.

Answer (score 1):

you should probably know everything on this list:

http://www.faculty.ucr.edu/~tgirke/Documents/UNIX/linux_manual.html

maybe not everything is essential all the time, but knowing at least a cursory overview of each can help a lot for basic functionality.

Answer (score 1):

perl, xargs, lsof, find, grep, bash, tar, gzip, tr, tail, diff, patch, and bc.

And everything that is in [SUS2](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcuix.html) (Single UNIX Specification).

Answer (score 0):

Like you mentioned, learn awk, sed and grep. They will be very good friends of yours.
Also, very important, learn to use properly a text editor such as vim.

I would also recommend you to get familiar with a good scripting language such as perl or python.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the commands directly. Rather when you find yourself struggling with something try a few quick Google and man page searches and see how you can improve what you're trying to do right then and there. Keep it relevant and you will get more useful results.